# .setText not working properly

Tags: android

So I'm in a basic part of my application I'm wanting to make. I've never gotten this error before, and I don't know what's going on. My .setText is throwing an error saying "setText cannot be resolved or is not a field" I've looked around and haven't been able to find my problem. I believe I'm doing it correctly. If anyone could help me out that'd be great!

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final TextView loading_Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
final EditText name_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
//String Values
    String Age="";
    String Name = name_Edit.getText().toString();

//Int Values
    int Gender = 0; //1 male | 2 female
    int Group = 0; //Different groups for ages and genders
    int save_Info = 0; //save info to phone


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button male_Button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button female_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    male_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Gender++;//Adds one to show this user is a male.

            loading_Text.setText=(Name);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Change to  loading_Text.setText(Name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw two problems:

**First:**

`loading_Text.setText=(Name);`

Should be

`loading_Text.setText("The text you want to set");`

You'll need to take a look at the [API document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to see how to call the method.

**Second:**

Move these part:

```
final TextView loading_Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
final EditText name_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
//String Values
    String Age="";
    String Name = name_Edit.getText().toString();
```

inside your `onCreate`, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView loading_Text;
EditText name_Edit;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loading_Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    name_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Or you'll get `NullPointerException`.

This is because you were trying to reach the View's property before the view is being initialized. View will be initialized after `setContentView`, and what you were intend to do was `findViewById` from `R.layout.activity_main` before it had been loaded.

Similarly, you'll need to move this call of method:

`String Name = name_Edit.getText().toString();`

somewhere after `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

`setText` is a function. So you would need to pass `name` as a argument. 
like `loading_Text.setText(Name);`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    loading_Text.setText=(Name);
```

to this:

```
    loading_Text.setText(Name);
```

Also, if you don't see anything in the textview, it is because you are getting the edittext's text before you even create your views, I use an on edittext listener like this to refresh the String when the edit text is changed:

```
name_Edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

              Name = name_Edit.getText().toString();    
          }
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
```

I hope this works for you :)